# css nth-child selector formula

Tags: css-selectors

I have a list of html items and I need to select every 3 over 3. (1,2,3,7,8,9,13,14,15 e.t.c)

Please suggest me, is it possible to do using css nth-child selector and what formula should be in parentheses? Or only way is JavaScript?

Comment: Need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray! I've found the solution! Thanks for your answers!
My version is:

```
.item:nth-child(1+6n),
.item:nth-child(2+6n),
.item:nth-child(3+6n) {
   /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all the elements of the same type? You might be able to use :nth-of-type(3). :nth-child selects children of children too if I am not mistaking.

Comment: Yes, all of the elements are the same type - it is an items of the unordered list. The feature is that the items are generated dynamically, so I don't know exact number of them.

Comment: You could use :nth-of-type(odd) and :nth-of-type(even).

Answer (score 0):

What is your scenario(purpose)? There are many way to archive it ~

Here is one way use override technique:

```
li:nth-of-type(n+13) {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-of-type(n+10) {
    color: red;
}    
li:nth-of-type(n+7) {
    color: green;
}
li:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    color: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(n+1) {
    color: green;
}
```

I have write a simple demo with SCSS here:

https://jsbin.com/gihuki/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: A have adaptive layout with list of items, where each item has photo and text. On desktop version fits 3 items in each row. By designer's idea, items of even row has photo floated to left and the odd row items with right float for image. When screen gets narrower, every row will fit 2 items, and just one item for mobile version. So I need solution which won't depend from number of items in each row.

Comment: Just give each row a class name (odd and even). and use @media query to solve this problem.

Comment: It was my first think) For desktop version it would be best solution. But for tablet and mobile version it isn't appliable. In desktop version three item in one row and in one container. But in the tablet version only two left in first row, when third goes to the next row.